# How to combine to sql columns with different lengths?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two SQL queries that when run, the first forms this:

```
SELECT c.cid, title, name, weighting, mark 
FROM Grade g 
 JOIN Assessment a ON g.aid = a.aid 
 JOIN Course c ON a.cid = c.cid 
WHERE sid = 'S0001';
```

```
+--------------------------------------------+
-cid --- table - name - weighting - mark 
-c1 ----OOP---A1--------20--------50--
-c1 ----OOP---A2--------20--------50--
-c1 ----OOP---A3--------20--------50--
-c1 ----OOP---A4--------20--------50--
-c1 ----OOP---A5--------20--------50--
-c2 ----OOP---A1--------20--------72--
-c2 ----OOP---A2--------20--------65--
-c2 ----OOP---EX--------20--------50--
-c3 ----OOP---A1--------20--------50--
-c3 ----OOP---A2--------20--------72--
-c3 ----OOP---A3--------20--------65--
-c3 ----OOP---EX--------20--------65--
+--------------------------------------------+
```

and the second forms this:

```
SELECT cid, SUM(mark*weighting)/100 AS Final 
FROM Grade g 
  JOIN Assessment a ON g.aid = a.aid 
WHERE sid = 'S0001' 
GROUP BY cid;
```

```
+--------------+
-cid----final 
-c1 ----60---
-c2 ----65---
-c3 ----65---
+--------------+
```

How do i combine the two query's so i can add the final column to the initial one and it looks like this?

```
+--------------------------------------------+
-cid --- table - name - weighting - mark - final
-c1 ----OOP---A1--------20--------50--------60
-c1 ----OOP---A2--------20--------50--
-c1 ----OOP---A3--------20--------50--
-c1 ----OOP---A4--------20--------50--
-c1 ----OOP---A5--------20--------50--
-c2 ----OOP---A1--------20--------72--------65
-c2 ----OOP---A2--------20--------65--
-c2 ----OOP---EX--------20--------50--
-c3 ----OOP---A1--------20--------50--------70
-c3 ----OOP---A2--------20--------72--
-c3 ----OOP---A3--------20--------65--
-c3 ----OOP---EX--------20--------65--
```

I've tried a multitude of things but nothing really seems to work, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance! (The final column doesn't correspond to any of the other columns besides cid).

Comment: yes i did :( it still came up with an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT 
    c.cid, 
    title, 
    name, 
    weighting, 
    mark,
    SUM(mark*weighting) OVER(PARTITION BY c.cid) final
FROM Grade g 
JOIN Assessment a ON g.aid = a.aid 
JOIN Course c ON a.cid = c.cid 
WHERE sid = 'S0001';
```

Or if you just want the `final` for the "top" row per group:

```
SELECT 
    c.cid, 
    title, 
    name, 
    weighting, 
    mark,
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITIN BY c.cid ORDER BY name) = 1 
        THEN SUM(mark*weighting) OVER(PARTITION BY c.cid)
    END final
FROM Grade g 
JOIN Assessment a ON g.aid = a.aid 
JOIN Course c ON a.cid = c.cid 
WHERE sid = 'S0001'
ORDER BY cid, name
```

I would strongly recommend prefixing *all* the columns that are used in the query with the alias of the table they belong to, so the query is unambiguous and easier to understand for someone that has no knowledge of your data structures.

In ealier versions, you can join an aggregate query, or use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT 
    c.cid, 
    title, 
    name, 
    weighting, 
    mark,
    x.final
FROM Grade g 
JOIN Assessment a ON g.aid = a.aid 
JOIN Course c ON a.cid = c.cid 
JOIN (
    SELECT cid, SUM(mark*weighting)/100 AS Final 
    FROM Grade g 
    JOIN Assessment a ON g.aid = a.aid 
    WHERE sid = 'S0001' 
    GROUP BY cid
) x ON x.cid = c.cid
WHERE sid = 'S0001'
```

Comment: ahh the third query works! after taking a look it makes so much sense- i cant thank you enough :)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT c.cid,
       title,
       name,
       weighting,
       mark,
       SUM(mark*weighting)/100 AS FINAL
FROM Grade g
JOIN Assessment a ON g.aid = a.aid
JOIN Course c ON a.cid = c.cid
HAVING sid = 'S0001';
```

Try this out! It may help you?
Since `SUM` is an aggregate function in SQL using `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` will workout.

Comment: thank you! although it still flagged up an error :(

Comment: can you send me a screenshot?

Comment: SELECT c.cid, title, name, weighting, mark, SUM(mark*weighting)/100 AS Final FROM Grade g JOIN Assessment a ON g.aid = a.aid JOIN Course c ON a.cid = c.cid HAVING sid = 'S0001';

Comment: Above query may word as SUM is an aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

```
select cid,title,name,weighting, case when top = 1 then final end as final
from (
       select a.cid as cid,title,name,weighting,b.Final as Final , 
       row_number() over(partition by a.cid order name ) as top
       from
           (SELECT c.cid, title, name, weighting, mark 
            FROM Grade g 
            JOIN Assessment a ON g.aid = a.aid 
            JOIN Course c ON a.cid = c.cid 
             WHERE sid = 'S0001'
           ) A,
          (SELECT cid, SUM(mark*weighting)/100 AS Final 
           FROM Grade g 
           JOIN Assessment a ON g.aid = a.aid 
           WHERE sid = 'S0001' 
           GROUP BY cid
          )B
where a.cid = b.cid
)
```